# Access [FromBody] from a Custom Attribute

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a asp.net core MVC app.
I want to create a Custom Log Attribute to track all the information happened to the server. Especially for the ones with [HttpPost] and [FromBody]

For example:

```
    [AuditLog]
    public async Task<JsonResult> SignIn([FromBody] SignInModel model)
```

Inside the AuditLog, I want to have access to the [FromBody] model instance.
Is this possible?

Comment: Did my answer provide enough assistence to fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible for your attributes to access arguments at the time the (action) method is called.

Instead, you could create an action filter. In this filter you can access the passed `signInModel` value and also check for the presense of the `[AuditLog]` attribute.

Something like this:

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
  var parameters = context.ActionDescriptor.Parameters;
  foreach (ControllerParameterDescriptor p in parameters) {
    var attributes = p.ParameterInfo.CustomAttributes;
    if (
      attributes.Any(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(FromBodyAttribute))
    ) {
      var yourModelValue = context.ActionArguments[p.Name];
      // DO SOMETHING HERE...
      break;
    }
  }
}
```